# java generic method invocation conversion error

Tags: java, list, generics, hashmap, type-conversion

I have piece of code I use to generate charts:

```
HashMap<String, List<Ticket>> openedTicketsPerTeam = getOpenedTicketsPerTeam();
```

How should I write **signature of generic method** to count length of list, every Map element?
My idea was:

```
Map<String, Integer> getNumOfValuesPerKey(HashMap<String, List<? extends Object>> map) {...}
```

but after invocation there's conversion error:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> numOfTicketsPerTeam = getNumOfValuesPerKey(openedTicketsPerTeam );
```

Comment: can you post the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (could be used for **any** key `K` and any list of `V`s):

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, Integer> getNumOfValuesPerKey(Map<K, List<V>> map) {

    Map<K, Integer> count = new HashMap<K, Integer>();

    for (Entry<K, List<V>> entry : map.entrySet()) 
        count.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().size());

    return count;
}
```

---

### Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

    map.put("Hello", Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    map.put("World", Arrays.asList(4,5));

    System.out.println(getNumOfValuesPerKey(map));
}
```

Output:

```
{Hello=3, World=2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map<String, Integer> numOfTicketsPerTeam = getNumOfValuesPerKey(openedTicketsPerTeam );
```

Your method (correctly) returns `Map<String, Integer>`, but you are assigning it to a `HashMap<String, Integer>` - there are multiple types of Map, the compiler has no way of knowing your implementation returns a HsshMap.

Note that you can, and should, simplify your method signature to:

```
Map<String, Integer> getNumOfValuesPerKey(Map<String, List<?>> map) {...}
```

Changes are to make the parameter a `Map` (not a `HashMap`) and `List<?>` (not `List<? extends Object>`, which is the same thing but more cruft)

Answer (score 0):

No need to parameterize over the value type actually. The problem you had with `Map<K, List<?>>` is that non-wildcard generic parameters must match exactly. So in the second type parameter of `Map`, `List<?>` does not match `List<Ticket>`. The correct thing to do is to make that a wildcard also (with the added benefit of being able to work with implementing classes e.g. `ArrayList` as the parameter):

```
public static <K> Map<K, Integer> getNumOfValuesPerKey(Map<K, ? extends List<?>> map) {

    Map<K, Integer> count = new HashMap<K, Integer>();

    for (Map.Entry<K, ? extends List<?>> entry : map.entrySet()) 
        count.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().size());

    return count;
}
```